# Query data in Powerpoint

Tags: automation, microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-powerpoint-2010, query

I would like to build an MS PowerPoint 2010 presentation where some of the displayed data would be queried from an external source (I am flexible - the simpler the better, I need to update that external source manually). The dynamic data would typically be

- numbers
- conditions (if the data queried is "1" then place a red dot, if "2" than place a green dot")

Is this at all possible? If so, what should I look for first (I am ready to learn new things here but I have no idea where to start).

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short and in theory, this is possible.  Microsoft Office uses a scripting language called Visual Basic For Application (VBA) to allow you to perform some relatively powerful tasks like manipulating objects within PowerPoint and pull/update information from external sources like an Access database or SQL server using an already available package called ADO.  Microsoft calls it "Macros", but you can do Ctrl+F11 to get access to the scripting area.

Unfornately, this isn't exaclty trivial and anything further would be better suited for [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com) on the details of **HOW** to do such a thing.

Comment: Thanks. I knew of VBA (tried some years ago to use it with Excel) and I was hoping there would be an easier way -- but anyways I will give another try to VBA.